# How to register debian uefi file with my motherboard?

Tags: debian, uefi

I moved the disk with my debian installation to another computer, and it wouldn't boot. Using systemrescuecd I mounted my uefi partition (512 MB, vfat filesystem, has EFI directory) and did `cd /mnt/sda1 && mkdir BOOT && cp debian/grubx64.efi BOOT/bootx64.efi`, and it booted fine. (got the advice at [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/380564/378557)) Now how do I register *debian/grubx64.efi* file with my system so that I can get rid of *BOOT/bootx64.efi*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems and `man grub-install` I did `sudo grub-install --efi-directory $MY_ESP_MOUNTPOINT --target=x86_64-efi` and now I have a "debian" boot target listed and working.

Answer (score 6):

You can list and manipulate the EFI boot entries with `efibootmgr` on Linux.

Once you've successfully booted the system manually, make sure that `efibootmgr` is installed:

```
apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Then make sure the `efivars` pseudo-filesystem is mounted RW:

```
mount -o remount,rw -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

If that command fails, or if running `efibootmgr` results in a message like `EFI variables are not supported on this system.` then you did not boot in EFI mode.  Reboot and try again.

Finally, add `debian/grubx64.efi` to the EFI boot list and make it the default:

```
efibootmgr -c -p 1 -d /dev/sda -L "GRUB" -l '\efi\debian\grubx64.efi'
```

The `-p 1` and `-d /dev/sda` options specify the partition and block device containing the EFI system partition where you created the BOOT sub-directory.  `-L` is a label for the entry being created, and `-l` is the path to the boot-loader.

You can delete entries you don't want with `efibootmgr -b <boot-entry> -B`.

You can get a detailed list of the current EFI boot entries with `efibootmgr -v`.

See `man efibootmgr` for details.  I recommend reading it thoroughly and googling or asking here for clarification **before** running any of the above commands.

Comment: note: this is how to do it manually.  Running `grub-install` or `update-grub` should do much of the above automatically if you have `grub-efi-amd64` (or `grub-efi-ia32` on a 32-bit x86 machine) installed. You may need to manually mount the EFI partition user /boot manually, I can't recall exactly.

Comment: `grub-install` with appropriate options did it

Comment: Could be just `grub-install` in a chroot with /dev, /proc and maybe /sys (bind)mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the command

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory $MY_ESP_MOUNTPOINT --force-extra-removable --recheck
```

With `--force-extra-removable` Debian will (as Redhat does) create the BOOT directory in the EFI directory just along with the Debian directory. Most BIOS (like HP BIOS for example and I feel recent Dell BIOS) use this BOOT directory to find the file `BOOTX64.EFI` and automatically create the Boot entry making the UEFI boot automatically.

The `--target` option is not mandatory as you Debian will automatically set the right value if you run the grub-install from the same binary type as the system you want to boot

`--recheck` is here just to recreate the UEFI table and clear old boot entries no longer relevant as you could do with `-B` option in `efibootmgr`.